# script.js:28 Uncaught ReferenceError: isValidCVC is not defined i keep getting not defined in my console

Tags: javascript, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

this is the JavaScript code that is use to process payment using paypal API but its seems am missing something or not writing some function well because i keep getting undefined in my console when i enter the CVC/CVV code and submit i get error

```
// Set up PayPal API credentials
const CLIENT_ID = "'";
const CLIENT_SECRET = "";
const PAYPAL_API_URL = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment";

// Get form fields
const expiryDateField = document.getElementById("expiry-date");
const cvcField = document.getElementById("cvc");
const billAmountField = document.getElementById("bill-amount");

// Set up event listener for pay button
document.getElementById("pay-button").addEventListener("click", function () {
    const cardNumber = document.getElementById("card-number").value;

    // Validate card details
    if (cardNumber === null || cardNumber.trim() === "") {
        alert("Please enter a valid credit card number.");
        return false;
    }

    const expiryDate = expiryDateField.value;
    if (!isValidExpiryDate(expiryDate)) {
        alert("Please enter a valid expiration date (MM/YY).");
        return;
    }

    const cvc = cvcField.value;
    if (!isValidCVC(cvc)) {
        alert("Please enter a valid CVV/CVC code.");
        return;
    }

    const billAmount = billAmountField.value;
    if (!isValidBillAmount(billAmount)) {
        alert("Please enter a valid monthly bill amount.");
        return;
    }

    // Create payment payload
    const payload = {
        intent: "sale",
        payer: {
            payment_method: "credit_card",
            funding_instruments: [{
                credit_card: {
                    number: cardNumber,
                    type: getCardType(cardNumber),
                    expire_month: parseInt(expiryDate.split("/")[0]),
                    expire_year: parseInt("20" + expiryDate.split("/")[1]),
                    cvv2: cvc
                }
            }]
        },
        transactions: [{
            amount: {
                total: parseFloat(billAmount) * 1.03,
                currency: "USD",
                details: {
                    subtotal: billAmount,
                    tax: parseFloat(billAmount) * 0.03
                }
            },
            description: "Monthly bill payment"
        }]
    };

    // Send payment request to PayPal API
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 201) {
                const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                alert("Payment processed successfully! Payment ID: " + response.id);
            } else {
                console.log(xhr.responseText); // Log the error response
                alert("Error processing payment. Please try again later.");
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.open("POST", PAYPAL_API_URL);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(payload));
});
function isValidExpiryDate(expiryDate) {
    // Check that expiry date is in the format "MM/YY"
    if (!/^\d{2}\/\d{2}$/.test(expiryDate)) {
        return false;
    }

    // Parse month and year from expiry date string
    const month = parseInt(expiryDate.split("/")[0]);
    const year = parseInt(expiryDate.split("/")[1]);

    // Check that month and year are valid
    const currentDate = new Date();
    const currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear() % 100; // Get last two digits of current year
    if (year < currentYear || year > currentYear + 10 || month < 1 || month > 12) {
        return false;
    }

    // Check if expiry date is in the past
    if (year === currentYear && month < currentDate.getMonth() + 1) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

so am getting error when i test a CVV/CVC credit code using paypal API but i keep getting undefined

Comment: I'm just wondering, what's the difference, if SO tells you `isValidCVC` doesn't exist in your code, or an error message tells you that?

Comment: @Teemu i get error message in the console that isValidCVC is not defined

Comment: Yes, then you need to define the function.

Comment: any example of how i can do that

Comment: hello folks have been able to figure it out , forgot i have to define isValidCVC function.